# Borrar subcarpetas y no la raiz -batch windows

Tags: batch

Buen día, necesito un batch para eliminar las subcarpetas dentro de una subcarpeta sin eliminar la raiz del mismo. O sea:

Carpeta_padre (No borrar) Carpeta_Hija (No borrar) Carpeta subhija (Borrar) Archivos (Borrar)

Lo dificil de esto es que la "carpeta_Hija" puede tener cualquier nombre.

Les muestro el batch:

```
del /q C:\Carpeta_padre\* 
for /d %%x in (C:\Carpeta_padre*.*) DO RD /s /q "%%x"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Breve explicación

### Método a usar

Crearemos una función que recorrerá la carpeta abuelo, creando dentro del mismo bucle otro bucle que recorra las carpetas padre obteniendo así las carpetas hijo y vaciándolas en el acto para después borrarlas. Los archivos dentro de la carpeta padre se mantendrán pero sus subcarpetas serán eliminadas.

### Orden de carpetas

La carpeta maestra o carpeta abuelo contiene dentro la carpeta padre, dentro de la carpeta padre se encuentran las carpetas hijos (nuestro objetivo a ser eliminado).

## Código

```
@echo off
REM Llamamos a la funcion y le pasamos la carpeta abuelo
call :_LimpiezaDeHijos "test"

REM Rompemos la rutina para no volver a llamar a la funcion por error
exit

REM Definimos la funcion
:_LimpiezaDeHijos
REM Recorremos la carpeta abuelo
for /d %%a in (%~1/*) do (
    REM Recorremos cada carpeta dentro de la carpeta abuelo
    for /d %%b in (%~1/%%a/*) do (
        REM Vaciamos y removemos la carpeta hijo
        del /q %~1\%%a\%%b* 
        rd /q /s %~1\%%a\%%b
    )
)
```

### Extra

Supongamos que luego quisieras hacer que todas las carpetas a partir de la carpeta hijo sean borradas. Dentro del bucle podrías crear un método que vaya vaciando carpeta por carpeta hasta que la carpeta hijo se pueda borrar.

Más o menos:

```
if exist  %%a/* {
    del /q %%a/*
    rd /q /s %%a
} else {
    del /q %%a
}
```